# How can I ensure that multiple firebase requests are all completed successfully?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using firebase in my android application and I am trying to sign up new users with a name and username attached to the new users. The following Firebase requests are being made to achieve this:

1. createAccount (register email/password auth account)
2. createNewUser (set a user value in the database with an email, name, and username)
3. registerUsernameTaken (register the username with the userId in a seperate database node to be able to check if a username is taken in the future)

My problem is that if any of these actions fail, I don't want any of the actions to complete. For instance, if createAccount completes successfully but createNewUser doesn't, I now have a new account without the associated name and username account information properly registered along with the username registeration uncompleted. What is the best way to ensure that either all or none of the listed firebase requests are completed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `onCompleteListener` to the method/task you want to ensure that it will be complete like this.

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, , new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                          // Handle task not successful 
                        } else {
                          // Handle task successful 
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Hope it's help

Comment: This does not answer the question. I want to know how to call multiple requests at once. This is a single request with an onComplete listener, which is what i'm already doing.